# How to switch user controls with shared viewmodel dynamically?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, .net-core

I have a window separated into two horizontal halves that contain user controls, let's call them Left and Right for simplicity. Both Left and Right can contain some views: Left shows either Left1, Left2 or Left3, while Right always shows RightTop in the top half of Right, and either RightBottom1 or RightBottom2 on the bottom half. All Left-related user controls use the LeftViewmodel, whereas all Right-related user controls use the RightViewmodel.

[image]

I am trying to use the MVVM framework to dynamically switch between views, but most answers to similar questions rely on the fact that different views have different viewmodels, which means that the app should show the view based on the currently active viewmodel.

In my case though, not all separate views need to have their separate viewmodels, as all the information they require is contained in either LeftViewmodel or RightViewmodel. How can I make use of MVVM to dynamically switch views, for example when a menu button or something is selected?

Comment: What do you mean with switching ? Usually the parent Views VM is shared to all children. Set the DataContext of LeftView and RighView, and all the children will have same ViewModel

Comment: The left and right halves have separate functionalities, so I didn't want to give them a shared viewmodel. By switching I mean that for *Left*, only one of the three views is shown at a time, and for *Right*, RightTop is always visible whereas on the bottom, only RightBottom1 is shown or RightBottom2 is shown.

Comment: I misinterpreted the second part of your sentence, I see what you mean now. I have assigned LeftViewmodel to Left and RightViewmodel to Right, so you mean that I do not need to explicitly define the data context for Left1,2,3 and RightTop,Bottom1,Bottom2, correct?

Comment: Yes, those are all inherited from the parent control which will be Left and Right

Comment: Gotcha, but how do I make sure only one of each view option is shown at a time in each half using MVVM?

Comment: Assuming that Left1/2/3 operate on the same view model instance, you can obviously not switch between them by switching a view model, since the latter doesn't happen. You have to show them explicitly.

Comment: First of all... that is another question... second, that depends on your logic... You could make a boolean for each view, whcih you could bind to the Visibility of the Views with a BoolToVisibilityConverter

Comment: @JansthcirlU: The question is where and how your logic that decides whether Left1 or Left2 should be displayed is defined?

Comment: @mm8 I was thinking about having a button that shows the possible views when hovered over, and that clicking the appropriate option should make the view change.

Comment: @JansthcirlU: That doesn't answer my question, does it? Where is the logic that is being executed when you click the button defined?

Comment: Oh, I haven't written that out yet, I was hoping there would be an MVVM way to do it inside xaml or something.

Comment: should Left1 and Left2 use the same ViewModel TYPE, e.g Left1 has a LeftViewModel instance as datacontext and Left2 has another LeftViewModel instance as datacontext., OR should they use the same ViewModel INSTANCE. e.g. share the same data. I think the latter one could be done with dataTemplates and some tricks.

Comment: They should share the same instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with everything in WPF and MVVM, there's always multiple ways to do things. But, here is my perspective on it:

Since you are sharing your two view-models with multiple views:

- You need to have state in each view-model to determine which views to
  display. This could be simple bool properties. IsRightBottom1Visible
  or IsRightBottom2Visible, etc.
- In your XAML, bind the Visibility of
  your views to your new properties, and use a
  BooleanToVisibilityConverter to show/hide.
- For your menu or buttons,
  you can bind them to ICommand properties in your view-models and use
  a RelayCommand to set your bool properties.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will give this question a little bit more time before I mark this as the answer, but I think I am going to go with this approach!